# Louis's reaction to his wife's pregnancy

Tags: plot-explanation, character, interview-with-the-vampire

How do you think Louis reacted when he found out that his wife was pregnant in *Interview with the Vampire*?

After the way he behaves with Claudia he seemed to be a very caring father. In the scenario his wife was older than him, maybe it lasted until they had a child and that's why he suffered so much and shows his love as a father to Claudia. Maybe knowing if his child was a girl or a boy would also help in explanining this.

Comment: You didn't need to delete the previous version of this question and re-post it, you could have just edited it.

Comment: Yes, in general, please try to avoid asking the same question over and over again just because it hasn't gotten an answer yet. I'll leave this new version around since you've removed parts that were superfluous in the original question. It's acknowledged that you care very much about Louis and his family, but please try to channel your efforts a little more and get acquainted with how this site works a little more, so you don't have to throw questions at the wall in 3 different versions and see which one sticks.

Comment: As to the question itself, I'm not entirely sure if this is within the realms of understanding the film in contrast to speculating about the characters' life outside of the story. It does seem it might be possible to guide it into direction more relevant for the film itself, though, so I'd encourage further revisions of this (but preferably by [edit]ing the question itself as opposed to reasking it a 5th time).

Comment: I'll also add that if you have too many deleted questions, you could end up triggering an automatic ban that would prevent you from asking any further questions. I don't (and can't) know how close you are to that line, but I'd definitely recommend you edit future questions instead of deleting and re-posting them.

Comment: The problem is that in the books, Louis wasn't married before being turned, but lived with father and brother, so it's not like there is even another source to pull from to better speculate on the film's choice with this change. I think it is unfortunately only going to attract very opinion-based answers, which are against the sites rules.

Comment: However the books lend themselves more heavily to Louis' Catholic background along with his brother's religious visions that Louis didn't take seriously. After his brother dies soon after a fight with Louis, this prompts Louis to long for death, but it's the Religious aspects that drive his characters over all motivations.  One could argue the wife and child change points to Mary and Jesus parallels instead, which lends itself to his failed redemption through Claudia and Madeline...